# Speed up numpy filtering

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, png

I am making a music recognition program, and as part of it, I need to find the largest connected areas of a numpy array from a png (2200x1700 pixels). My current solution is the following.

```
labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)
cutoff = len(blobs)*len(blobs[0]) / nlabels
blobs_found = 0
x = []
t1 = time()
for n in range(1, nlabels+1):
    squares = np.where(labels==n)
    if len(squares[0]) < cutoff:
        blobs[squares] = 0
    else:
        blobs_found += 1
        blobs[squares] = blobs_found
        x.append(squares - np.amin(squares, axis=0, keepdims=True))
nlabels = blobs_found
print(time() - t1)
```

This works, but it takes ~6.5 seconds to run. Is there a way I could remove the loop from this code (or otherwise speed it up)?

Comment: That's an interesting question, could you make it [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the size (in pixels) of each labelled region with:

```
unique_labels = numpy.unique(labels)
label_sizes = scipy.ndimage.measurement.sum(numpy.ones_like(blobs), labels, unique_labels)
```

The largest will then be:

```
unique_labels[label_size == numpy.max(label_size)]
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to make the last line be a list of the n largest labels?

Comment: Yes, use `numpy.argsort` instead and take the first n values, something like: `unique_labels[numpy.argsort(label_size)[0:n-1]]`

Comment: Should `ndimage.measurement.sum` be ndimage.sum in new versions?

Comment: @OscarSmith: yes.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest would probably be to use `numpy.bincount` and work from there. Something like:

```
labels, nlabels = ndimage.label(blobs)
cutoff = len(blobs)*len(blobs[0]) / float(nlabels)

label_counts = np.bincount(labels)

# Re-label, taking the cutoff into account
cutoff_mask = (label_counts >= cutoff)
cutoff_mask[0] = False
label_mapping = np.zeros_like(label_counts)
label_mapping[cutoff_mask] = np.arange(cutoff_mask.sum()) + 1

# Create an image-array with the updated labels
blobs = label_mapping[labels].astype(blobs.dtype)
```

This could be optimized for speed some more, but I aimed for readability.